# Access not inserting new values into table

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am attempting to insert a new product with a product code and a serial number value into my sales table in my sales database. The following code writes to the table:

```
// This function queries the database and updates it with new data.
public void updateTbl(String update) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(update);
    stmt.close();
}
```

along with:

```
// This SQL query inserts a record into the product database
public void addToSalesDatabase(String inPC, String inSN) {
    try {
        prod.updateTbl("INSERT INTO SalesTbl (ProductCode, SerialNum)\nVALUES('" 
                + inPC + "','" + inSN + "')");
    } catch(SQLException se) {
        System.out.println(se);
    }
}
```

where inPC is the product code as a string and inSN is the serial number as a string.

I will include one example of a combination product code and serial number that doesn't work:

Product Code: RT2MP602812B

Serial Number: S/N:201908050438

The only time the values are written to the table is when I create a SQL query in Access directly. Through the application, it doesn't seem to work at all.

At first, I suspected that it could be the inclusion of "S/N:" in the serial number string but when tested with other codes that also include "S/N:" it works. This issue seems to occur at random and I cannot pinpoint where the problem lies.

Comment: What Java version and JDBC driver do you use? Did you try to call `conn.commit()`?

Comment: @vanje I have now discovered that the insert function works on my computer, however, it doesn't work on the server where the application is being used.

I am running Java Version 8 Update 291 (build 1.8.0_291-b10). I am using ucanaccess-4.0.4.jar library.

I have not tried that at all. Should I call conn.commit() after conn.createStatement()?

Comment: You should call commit() after the insert. Unless you have autocommit activated, the commit() ends the transaction and writes the data to the database. In case of an error you would call rollback() instead. You should really learn more about transaction handling, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: Do you (mis)use an Access Database as a server database? Access is a desktop database and not intended to be used as a server database. For such a use case you should use SQLite or a real client server database system like MariaDB, PostgreSQL or MS SQL Server.

Comment: Access works just fine for me as a backend on a file server. However, my frontend is also an Access file so I really can't advise on JAVA issue. Why bother saving `S/N:` in data?

Comment: @vanje I will try calling commit() and see if that solves the problem. The application itself is client-side, it uses an Access database file located in the company server. It worked quite well in the past and it does everything that they need it to do.

Comment: @June7 It isn't up to me how the serial numbers are saved. As far as I have been made aware, whenever they use the barcode scanner to input a serial number into the application, the scanner will sometimes automatically insert S/N: automatically.